# How to aim the camera at the z-index of the cell in front of my character?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I've got a 3D terrain environment like so:

[image]

I'm trying to get the character (camera) to look up when climbing hills, and look down when descending, like climbing in real life.

This is what it's currently doing:

[image]

Right now the camera moves up and down the hills just fine, but I can't get the camera angle to work correctly. The only way I can think of aiming up or down depending on the terrain is getting the z-index of the cell my character is currently facing, and set that as the focus, but I really have no idea how to do that.

This is admittedly for an assignment, and we're intentionally not using objects so things are organized a little strangely.

Here's how I'm currently doing things:

```
const int M = 100;  // width
const int N = 100;  // height
double zHeights[M+1][N+1];  // 2D array containing the z-indexes of terrain cells
double gRX = 1.5;  // x position of character
double gRY = 2.5;  // y position of character
double gDirection = 45;  // direction of character
double gRSpeed = 0.05;  // move speed of character


double getZ(double x, double y)  // returns the height of the current cell
{
    double z = .5*sin(x*.25) + .4*sin(y*.15-.43);
    z += sin(x*.45-.7) * cos(y*.315-.31)+.5;
    z += sin(x*.15-.97) * sin(y*.35-8.31);

    double amplitute = 5;
    z *= amplitute;
    return z;
}

void generateTerrain()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= N; j++)
        {
            zHeights[i][j] = getZ(i,j);
        }
    }
}

void drawTerrain()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            glColor3ub( (i*34525+j*5245)%256, (i*3456345+j*6757)%256, (i*98776+j*6554544)%256);
            glVertex3d(i, j, getZ(i,j));
            glVertex3d(i, j+1, getZ(i,j+1));
            glVertex3d(i+1, j+1, getZ(i+1,j+1));
            glVertex3d(i+1, j, getZ(i+1,j));
        }
    }
}

void display()  // callback to glutDisplayFunc
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    double radians = gDirection /180.*3.141592654;  // converts direction to radians
    double z = getZ((int)gRX, (int)gRY);  // casts as int to find z-index in zHeights[][]
    double dx = cos(radians)*gRSpeed;
    double dy = sin(radians)*gRSpeed;
    double at_x = gRX + dx;
    double at_y = gRY + dy;
    double at_z = z;  // source of problem, no idea what to do

    gluLookAt(gRX, gRY, z + 2,  // eye position
              at_x, at_y, at_z + 2,  // point to look at,  also wrong
              0, 0, 1);   // up vector

    drawTerrain();
    glEnd();
}

void init()
{
    generateTerrain();
}
```

Comment: The cross product of your forward vector and up vector gives you a side vector. The cross product of your side vector and the current cell's normal vector will give you the direction you want to look at to "follow the slope". You can calculate the normal vectors by normalizing the cross product of the slope vectors of the cell. Since your height function is derivable, you can use the derivative to find your slopes vectors at any point. From your images though, following the curve smoothly doesn't seem to be a concern. In that case, you can simply compare nearby heights to find your slopes.

Comment: Addendum : You'll want to calculate normal vectors anyway if you want to do any shading.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see any reason to cast to `int` here:

```
double z = getZ((int)gRX, (int)gRY);
```

Just use the `double` values to get a smooth behavior.

Your basic approach is already pretty good. You take the current position (`gRX, gRY`), walk a bit in the viewing direction (`dx, dy`) and use that as the point to look at. There are just two small things that need adaptation:

```
double dx = cos(radians)*gRSpeed;
double dy = sin(radians)*gRSpeed;
```

Although multiplying by `gRSpeed` might be a good idea, in my opinion, this factor should not be related to the character's kinematics. Instead, this represents the smoothness of your view direction. Small values make the direction stick very closely to the terrain geometry, larger values smooth it out.

And finally, you need to evaluate the height at your look-at point:

```
double at_z = getZ(at_x, at_y);
```